# How to construct infinite products in constructive mathematics?

Tags: category-theory, constructive-mathematics

Maybe this is a very naive question because I don't know much about constructive mathematics besides basic definitions.

Well, according to [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constructive+mathematics) article, I can interpret most of mathematics in a topos with a natural number object. However, AC is not necessarily satisfied and in mathematics usually we consider infinite product of spaces, groups etc. using AC to guarantee that the product is not empty.
How can I guarantee that the product is not empty in constructive mathematics if AC is not satisfied?

Comment: The only way to guarantee $X$ nonempty is to exhibit an arrow $1\to X$ picking some element of $X$.  For example, with groups you are given an identity element arrow $1\to G$ as part of the group axioms so that doesn't need AC.

Comment: But first we should prove that $G$ is a group and proving that requires $G \neq \emptyset$, no?

Comment: That's what the user said : for each $G_i$, you are given in the structure a map $1\to G_i$; and this gives you automatically a map $1\to \displaystyle\prod_i G_i$

Comment: So a proof would go like this: Let $f_i : 1 \to G_i$ be the morfism who maps $f(\cdot) = e_i$ and let $f : 1 \to \prod_{i \in I} G_i$ be the map $f(\cdot) = (f_i(\cdot))_{i \in I}$. Then, as $(f_i(\cdot))_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i \in I} G_i$, we have $\prod_{i \in I} G_i \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: *morphism. I'm not an english speaker, sorry for the typo.